# How can I INDEX + AGGREGATE a data table finding to include another constraint filter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Goal: A source *Data Table* example displaying relevant Section phrases "in the box" depending on the content picked.

For example, presently referencing that *Data Table*'s "Section" column ($C:$C) for "Highlights" ($H$4) using...

I4    `=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($C:$C=$H$4),ROW(1:1))),"")`
I5    `=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($C:$C=$H$4),ROW(2:2))),"")`
I6    `=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($C:$C=$H$4),ROW(3:3))),"")`
I7    `=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C:$C)/($C:$C=$H$4),ROW(4:4))),"")`

... which presents the associated row's sentence string. But, as the screenshot shows, I can't figure limiting to also only the relevant book.

[image: BookSummaryExample screenshot]

Constraints: No Pivot, No VBA, No new O365 formula.

(I've considered having the "in the box" Section titles row position be depending on number of prior rows matching content rather than locked ($H$4), ($H$11), ($H$20), etc. I'll work that out later).

Thank you,

Comment: Off topic: If you have data tables, why use complete column references? This will result in calculating the cells in each row of the file versus each cell in the table.

Comment: On topic: try adding `($B:$B=$G$3)` to the array calculation inside AGGREGATE (and change it to table reference)

Comment: Agreed on Table references comment! My real file is using well, while this crafted example I just didn't set as table for no good reason. My bad.

Comment: Success! `/($B:$B=$G$3)` works! Unstuck from the mud, I can resume the rest... Thank you P.b!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to table references and adding an array which checks if the `Name` column equals the Book Picker value:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($D:$D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Table1[Section])/(Table1[Section]=$H$4)/(Table1[Name]=$G$3),ROW(1:1))),"")`